# Indexing or sorting dataframe using list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I wanted to sort the dataframe based on the list. Dataframe consists of unique id's and I have a list of ids.

Note:- list not have all id's value.
I used df.loc but it has limitations.

Example code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
ratings_dict = {
    "ID": ["101", "102", "103", "104", "105"],
    "title": ['TV', 'AC', 'Monitor', 'Headphone', 'Laptop'],
    "rating": [1, 2, 2, 3, 2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(ratings_dict)

trend_sort=["103","101"]
```

trend_sort is the id list.

```
df.set_index('ID',inplace=True)
df=df.loc[trend_sort]
```

After using df.loc I got output as,

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of, is creating a new list like this:

```
sorted_list = trend_sort + [i for i in df.index.tolist() if i not in trend_sort]
```

and then:

```
df = df.loc[sorted_list]
```

output:

```
    title   rating
ID      
103 Monitor   2
101 TV        1
102 AC        2
104 Headphone 3
105 Laptop    2
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, All solutions worked perfectly, but this solution is most time-efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the rank for each `ID` first, and then sort by the rank:

```
# to optimize the rank look up, store the rank / indices in a dictionary
rank = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(trend_sort)}
rank
# {'103': 0, '101': 1}

# map ID to the rank and if ID doesn't exist default to len of data frame
# so it will sorted to the end
df.loc[df.ID.map(lambda x: rank.get(x, len(df))).argsort()]

    ID      title  rating
2  103    Monitor       2
0  101         TV       1
1  102         AC       2
3  104  Headphone       3
4  105     Laptop       2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like:

```
df.reindex(pd.Index(trend_sort).append(df.index[~df.index.isin(trend_sort)]))
```

Output:

```
         title  rating
103    Monitor       2
101         TV       1
102         AC       2
104  Headphone       3
105     Laptop       2
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, using the `key=` parameter in `.sort_values`:

```py
df = df.sort_values(
    by="ID", key=lambda x: x.map({v: i for i, v in enumerate(trend_sort)})
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    ID      title  rating
2  103    Monitor       2
0  101         TV       1
1  102         AC       2
3  104  Headphone       3
4  105     Laptop       2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just attach the rest indices, no need to sort values, no map and no lambda:

```py
trend_sort=["103","101"]
new_idx = pd.Index(trend_sort).append(df.index.difference(trend_sort))
df.loc[new_idx]
```

```
         title  rating
      <object> <int64>
103    Monitor       2
101         TV       1
102         AC       2
104  Headphone       3
105     Laptop       2
```

Comment: I think I beat you to this solution. :-)   Reindex or loc pretty close to the same.  Reindex is little more flexible to handle values not in the index.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you really want.
but if you want the top column in the table to be columns in the trend_sort you can do the following

```
import pandas as pd
ratings_dict = {
    "ID": ["101", "102", "103", "104", "105"],
    "title": ['TV', 'AC', 'Monitor', 'Headphone', 'Laptop'],
    "rating": [1, 2, 2, 3, 2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(ratings_dict)

trend_sort=["103","101"]

def get_sort_value(item,trend_l):
    if item in trend_l:
        return trend_l.index(item)
    return len(trend_l)+1

df['sort_column'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: get_sort_value(x,trend_sort))
df = df.sort_values(by=['sort_column'])
df = df.drop(columns=['sort_column'])
print(df)
```